# Modal Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
`cell = '<div class="col-4"><div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">\
    <img class="card-img-top" src="products/'+thumb+ '" alt="Card image cap">\
<div class="card-body">\
    <h5 class="card-title">'+title+ '</h5>\
      <p class="card-text">'+cats+'</p>\
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show More</button>\
    </div>\
</div></div>
```

Code in another page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body">
      <span id="message">Thank You </span>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me. My modal doesnt show no matter how many times i try. Does modal work in bootstrap cards? No matter how many times i press the button the modal doesnt show. My modal is in another html page. Is there a problem with that? Im using visual studio code

Comment: Why would you expect something in another page to open in the first place?

Comment: Elaborate: What does "in another page" mean? What JavaScript are you including? Are you getting any errors in your console when the page loads or when the modal trigger is fired?

Comment: Please update you code so that it is more complete and even better: add a https://jsbin.com/?html,output example

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for the modal must be on (or available) to the page that you're calling it from and wanting it to pop up on. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
         stylesheets
         bootstrap javascript libraries
    </head>
    <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h2>
          <section>
              Content ....

              <button>Open the modal!</button>
          </section>


          <footer></footer>


          <div class="modal">
              Put modal at bottom
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, make sure that you are linking to the Bootstrap javascript files and jQuery for the modal to work. Bootstrap has a convenient CDN link for this at https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/